# Securing actuator endpoints except /health

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-boot-actuator

I want to secure my actuator endpoints with Spring Security except for /health endpoint

And I have this in my **application.yaml**

```
spring:
  security:
    user:
      name: admin
      password: ************
```

And this in my SecurityConfig

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .requestMatcher(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint().excluding("health")) 
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/health").permitAll() 
                .anyRequest().authenticated() 
                .and()
                .httpBasic(); 
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

But this config does not work as I want, because I still see the login form when I try to access **/actuator/health** endpoint

Maybe you have some suggestions so this will work.

I also think that maybe this is blocking code above from working as expected

```
management:
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: always
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
```

Comment: Just change `/health` to `/actuator/health` on ant matchers

Comment: If I change it like this **.antMatchers("/actuator/health").permitAll()** it still doesn't work, or do I need to change something in **.excluding()**?

Comment: then enable debug logs and update your question with the full debug logs so we can actually see what the server is doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution, and it works perfectly

```
http.requestMatcher(EndpointRequest.to("health"))
```

This will enable access to **/health** endpoint but will ask for credentials to any other endpoint